# Why "borrowed value does not live long enough" with Self but not specific type?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

The following code:

```rust
trait Passable: Sized {
    fn call<F: Fn(Self)>(f: F);
}

impl Passable for &[i32] {
    fn call<F: Fn(Self)>(f: F) {
        let vec = vec![1, 2, 3];
        f(&vec);
    }
}
```

gives the error

```
error[E0597]: `vec` does not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:8:11
  |
8 |         f(&vec);
  |           ^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
9 |     }
  |     - `vec` dropped here while still borrowed
```

By contrast, if I write the same thing but with a fixed type of `&[i32]` instead of `Self`, it compiles:

```rust
trait Passable: Sized {
    fn call<F: Fn(&[i32])>(f: F);
}

impl Passable for &[i32] {
    fn call<F: Fn(&[i32])>(f: F) {
        let vec = vec![1, 2, 3];
        f(&vec);
    }
}
```

Why does the first code fail but not the second? And can the first code be changed so that it does compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of lifetime elision. Your first example (with `Self`) is equivalent to this code:

```
trait Passable: Sized {
    fn call<F: Fn(Self)>(f: F);
}

impl<'a> Passable for &'a [i32] {
    fn call<F: Fn(&'a [i32])>(f: F) {
        let vec = vec![1, 2, 3];
        f(&vec);
    }
}
```

Note that here `f` takes an argument with *the same lifetime as `Self`* but `vec` has a smaller lifetime.

On the other hand, your second example is equivalent to this code:

```
trait Passable: Sized {
    fn call<'b, F: Fn(&'b [i32])>(f: F);
}

impl<'a> Passable for &'a [i32] {
    fn call<'b, F: Fn(&'b [i32])>(f: F) {
        let vec = vec![1, 2, 3];
        f(&vec);
    }
}
```

which uses different lifetimes for `Self` and the argument of `f`.